# Prove the edge with lightest weight exists in the set

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $H$ be a graph with each edge having an edge weight such that no 2 edges have the same weight. Consider $T$ as the minimum spanning tree of $H$. For any vertex $v$ in $H$ consider $E_v$ to be set of all edges that are incident with vertex $v$. Prove that for any vertex $v$ in the graph $H$, the edge with lightest weight in $E_v$ is an edge in $T$.

Suppose the edge with lightest weight of $E_v$ is not an edge in $T$.

Now I get a bit stuck because I know that the justification should be that we can form a more minimum tree, but I am not sure how to justify that exactly?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the lowest weight edge from $E_v$ to $T$ you formed a cycle. What happens if you take out the edge of maximum weight in this cycle after adding the edge. Do you get a new tree ? And the weight of this new tree is it smaller then the weight of $T$ ?

Comment: What do you mean "when you add this edge to $T$"? I am kind of confused there.

Comment: Consider the set of edges $T\cup E_v$. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: $E_v$ is the set of edges that have $v$ as an endpoint. So you are saying take $\alpha \in E_v$ with $\alpha$ having the lowest weight in $E_v$ and add it to $T$ you get a cycle?

Comment: Yes. I edit my answer. When you add $\alpha$ to $T$ you get a cycle. Do you see now ?

Comment: I am not understanding why it would form a cycle (+1)

Comment: When you add an edge to a tree it would automatically form a cycle. This is a very known property of tree.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory) You can see here to understand what I am trying to say